# Conceptual bug in a turtle program using resetscreen()

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Criteria I'm trying to meet:
The screen resets when the user presses the SPACEBAR, meaning the drawn lines go away and the unnamed turtle returns to the center but it ***doesn’t return to the default turtle color and shape!***

```
""" A simple drawing program

Click and drag the center turtle to draw
Click the colorful buttons to change the
turtle's color,
and then draw different shapes.
Press the SPACEBAR key to reset the
drawing.
"""

from turtle import *

turtle_1 = Turtle()
turtle_2 = Turtle()
turtle_3 = Turtle()

def callback_1(x,y):
    color("red")
    shape("circle")
    circle(100)

def callback_2(x,y):
    color("blue")
    shape("square")
    circle(100,steps=4)

def callback_3(x,y):
    color("green")
    shape("triangle")
    circle(100,steps=3)

def place_turtles():
    turtle_1.color("red")
    turtle_1.shape("circle")
    turtle_1.penup()
    turtle_1.goto(-200,-200)
    turtle_2.color("blue")
    turtle_2.shape("square")
    turtle_2.penup()
    turtle_2.goto(0,-200)
    turtle_3.color("green")
    turtle_3.shape("triangle")
    turtle_3.penup()
    turtle_3.goto(200,-200)

def start_over():
    resetscreen()
    place_turtles()

listen()
onkey(start_over, "space")

ondrag(goto)

place_turtles()
```

This code allows the user to drag the turtle, press buttons, and reset the screen when they press SPACEBAR. For some reason, though, resetting the screen also resets the color of the turtle. How can I prevent this from happening?

Basically what I want to happen is if, say, the user clicks on the blue square button, then resets the screen to hide the shape drawn by the button, all of the turtles return to their original positions, but the unnamed turtle does not change its previous color and shape. Let me know if I need to elaborate further.

Comment: What is `Turtle()`? I don't see it as part of `turtle` package. Is it a function/class you defined?

Comment: It's a class, but not one I defined. I generally use it when I need to name a new turtle/ draw using dormant copies of the turtle

Comment: Your problem description suggests that you need to save some data before resetscreen() and then use the data after place_turtles to restore the part you want kept.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes, I guess that's what I need. The shape of the turtle is not reset, just the color, though.. I'm not sure how I managed that.

Answer (score 0):

With a "better late than never" attitude, I believe I've reworked your code to get the behavior you desired.  I also reworked your drag logic to give you better drawing capability:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, getturtle

def callback_1(x, y):
    anonymous.color(*turtle_1.color())
    anonymous.shape(turtle_1.shape())
    anonymous.circle(100)

def callback_2(x, y):
    anonymous.color(*turtle_2.color())
    anonymous.shape(turtle_2.shape())
    anonymous.circle(100, steps=4)

def callback_3(x, y):
    anonymous.color(*turtle_3.color())
    anonymous.shape(turtle_3.shape())
    anonymous.circle(100, steps=3)

def setup_turtles():
    turtle_1.onclick(callback_1)
    turtle_1.color("red")
    turtle_1.penup()
    turtle_1.goto(-200, -200)

    turtle_2.onclick(callback_2)
    turtle_2.color("blue")
    turtle_2.penup()
    turtle_2.goto(0, -200)

    turtle_3.onclick(callback_3)
    turtle_3.color("green")
    turtle_3.penup()
    turtle_3.goto(200, -200)

def start_over():
    colors = anonymous.color()
    anonymous.reset()
    anonymous.color(*colors)

def drag_handler(x, y):
    anonymous.ondrag(None)  # disable event inside event handler
    anonymous.goto(x, y)
    anonymous.ondrag(drag_handler)  # reenable event on event handler exit

anonymous = getturtle()
anonymous.ondrag(drag_handler)

turtle_1 = Turtle(shape="circle")
turtle_2 = Turtle(shape="square")
turtle_3 = Turtle(shape="triangle")

setup_turtles()

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(start_over, "space")
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Many of the changes are just for personal style reasons.  The two key changes are: just reset the anonymous turtle itself, not the screen; rather than use `goto` as an event handler, wrap it in a function that turns off drag events during the `goto` call.